# How to generate a list of fakes using Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I want to generate a list of fakes without specify all the properties of the fake object using Moq :

```
var mock = Mock.Of<ICalendar>(x =>
    x.GetSchedules() == new List<ISchedule> 
    {
        // I don't want specify explicitly title and other properties
        Mock.Of<ISchedule>(y => y.Title == "fdfdf" && y.Start == DateTime.Today)
    });

List<ISchedule> s = mock.GetSchedules();
```

Is it possible to specify "rules" instead of hardcode properties ? And Is it possible to set the number of item I want ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
int numberOfElements = 10;
var mock = Mock.Of<ICalendar>(x =>
           x.GetSchedules() == Enumerable.Repeat(Mock.Of<ISchedule>(), numberOfElements).ToList());
```

Comment: Yeah it's the kind of result I expect. But i want that object are "filled" with random properties a little bit like MS Pex.

Finally I think it's out of scope of Mocking framework

Answer (score 1):

You could create a ScheduleMockBuilder abstract class that builds a Mock of ISchedule with some random data.
Then call this builder as many times as you need items in the list.

Check the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for more information.

You can also use [QuickGenerate](http://kilfour.wordpress.com/category/quickgenerate/); this is a library with a generic builder that a colleague of mine wrote. It can generate objects with random properties out of the box and you can even add constraints to the random data being generated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [AutoMoq](https://github.com/darrencauthon/AutoMoq) and see if that does what you want.